# Waiting for the cluster to join.... never ends redis-trib.rb Redis 3.2.9

Tags: ubuntu, redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

Trying to create Redis Cluster between 3 nodes on 3 three different servers connected over LAN.

Tried both

```
- src/redis-trib.rb create 192.168.148.20:6379 192.168.131.213:6379 192.168.142.199:6379

- src/redis-trib.rb create 192.168.148.20:7000 192.168.131.213:7000 192.168.142.199:7000
Each server has its config file

/etc/redis/redis.conf
nodes.conf
```

PORT 6379 & 16379 are open listining.

Result is the same:

```
root@localhost:~/build/redis-3.2.9# sudo src/redis-trib.rb create 192.168.148.20:6379 192.168.131.213:6379 192.168.142.199:6379

Creating cluster

Performing hash slots allocation on 3 nodes...

Using 3 masters:<br>
192.168.148.20:6379<br>
192.168.131.213:6379<br>
192.168.142.199:6379<br>
M: 2ef7f215c073d0e088ccf19a7b9038e26ba8e235 192.168.148.20:6379
slots:0-5460 (5461 slots) master<br>
M: 15016bba6c48f2e3957be95fb28b2e9c4f08d5b3 192.168.131.213:6379
slots:5461-10922 (5462 slots) master<br>
M: 069db7c66ef3bc38955786422c6697c3b30163e2 192.168.142.199:6379
slots:10923-16383 (5461 slots) master<br>
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes<br>
Nodes configuration updated<br>
Assign a different config epoch to each node<br>
Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster<br>
Waiting for the cluster to join..................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... .................................................................................................................... ..................................................................^C<br>
src/redis-trib.rb:653:in sleep': Interrupt from src/redis-trib.rb:653:inwait_cluster_join'<br>
from src/redis-trib.rb:1306:in create_cluster_cmd' from src/redis-trib.rb:1701:in<br>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each node communion port(10000+client port) can be access by other nodes.

$ sudo ufw allow from [other node ip] to any port [node communion port]